# FastAPI, robots.txt and noindex

Tags: fastapi, robots.txt, noindex

Does FastAPI need robots.txt and the tag noindex?
I am creating business api app which shouldn't be called by anonymous.
So I wonder whether I have to prepare robots.txt and the tag noindex in order to avoid any crawler's action or not.

I made robots.txt router as follows:

```
@router.get('/robots.txt')
def robots():
    data = """
    User-agent: *
    Disallow: /
    """
    return Response(content=data, media_type='text/plain')
```

Do I need another change?

Answer (score 4):

I tried this and it works

```
from fastapi.responses import PlainTextResponse
@app.get('/robots.txt', response_class=PlainTextResponse)
def robots():
    data = """User-agent: *\nDisallow: /"""
    return data
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped me a lot. One more suggestion: add `include_in_schema=False` in the decorator so it does not appear in the API documentation.